# How to return class name in collection instance in Laravel?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I return a collection like this

```
$posts = Posts::all();
$news = News::all();
$blog_posts = Blog::all();

$results = $posts->concat($news)->concat($blog_posts);

return response()->json($result);
```

How can I return the class name as part of the results, so I can determine which result is "post" which is "news" and which is "blog", because I will make a call with ajax and the `data` needs to have a `class` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is in each model class you can append attribute so you can determine what class it is

```
// Posts.php

protected $appends = ['class'];

public function getClassAttribute()
{
    return 'post';
}
```

Do that to each model class

Comment: It's not advisable to have so generic and (in most languages) reserved word there. Better something like `'model_custom_class'`.